# Is it possible to pass an whole array using custom field in wordpress?

Tags: post-meta

I want to pass array using a textarea custom field to single.php file but it`s not working using:

```
$cr_table_array_new = get_post_meta($postid, 'fields_details', true);
```

I defined array like this in a custom field.

[image]

Comment: Better to say you save array as text in database and you want to get it on single.php page. So, what is a value of `$cr_table_array_new` right now ?

Comment: I am doing this - $cr_table_array_new = get_post_meta($postid, 'fields_details', true);

Comment: I just want to initialize that variable with the whole array.

Comment: If you save multidimentional array as string/text, you will need to create recursive  function, which converts you text back to array. Isn't it better to save this array as array and work with it later using native php or wordpress functions?

Comment: @anton can you please show me an example ... :-)

Comment: That's not how you format an array for storage. You need to [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it. Or use JSON and decode it with `json_decode()`.